# Difference between PHP and JS evaluation of variables

Tags: php, javascript, evaluation, internals, ternary

Can someone please explain to me why the following javascript code produces an alert with 321 and the PHP code produces 1.

I know the PHP code evaluates the expression and returns true or false.  What I don't know is why in JavaScript it works like a ternary operator.  Is it just the way things were implemented in the language?

```
var something = false;
var somethingelse = (something || 321);
alert(somethingelse); // alerts 321
```

```
$var = '123';
$other = ($var || 321);
echo $other; // prints 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: in javascript "||" is coalesce oparetor, as short ternary ($a = $b ?: 1) comes with 5.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it just the way things were implemented in the language?

Yes, JavaScript does it a bit differently. The expression `(something || 321)` means if `something` is of a [falsy](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy) value, a default value of `321` is used instead.

In conditional expressions `||` acts as a logical `OR` as usual, but in reality it performs the same coalescing operation. You can test this with the following:

```
if ((0 || 123) === true)
    alert('0 || 123 evaluates to a Boolean');
else
    alert('0 || 123 does not evaluate to a Boolean');
```

In PHP the `||` operator performs a logical `OR` and gives a Boolean result, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised javascript did not alert 1 or true as well. The syntax you want for js is:

```
var somethingelse = something || 321;
```

Wrapping parentheses around something evaluates it as truthy / falsey. For php your are saying:

```
//$other will equal true if $var is true or 321 is true. 
$other = ($var || 321);
```

A matching statement in php would look like:

```
$other = ($var) ? $var : 321;
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if the parentheses are there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on boltClock answer since I can't comment - If you want it be a Boolean value you can parse it to bool like this:

```
var somthing = !!(somthingelse || 321);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP `($var || 321);` is evaluated and assigned to `$other`.

You can use this in PHP.

```
($other = $var) || $other = 321;
```

Update: As BoltClock said in Javascript `var somethingelse = (something || 321)`  seeks to assign a default value to the variable if `something` is false.